# Call a PHP variable to another PHP file

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass a variable from a `dbh.inc.php` to `index.php` using `include_once`, But it gives me an error in `$con` at `index.php` that it is not defined


dbh.inc.php:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "loginsystem";

$con = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

indux.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users;';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($resultCheck > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row['user_uid'] . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe the path for the include is wrong because there is nothing wrong with your code

Comment: If you put them in the same file it works?! If so then you are probably calling the file with the wrong path... if it doesn't it means that $con wasn't created because you didn't succeed in loggin in to you db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can access variables from one file to another by including file
like:

**vars.php**

```
<?php

$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';

?>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A

include 'vars.php';

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

?>
```

First of all check it by turning on the error reporting for that particular file and you will get error if the included path was not correct.

you can add it as follow:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Thanks